# Div not centered correctly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div that need to be exactly centered in the web page 
Here is the expected result
[image: expected result]

but here is the result that I can get
[image: wrong result]

this is my html

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
body {
  text-align: center
}
#menu {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
#logo {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
#right_side {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#profile_picture {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#arrow {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 7.5px;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#health_profile_title {
  float: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#short_ico {
  margin-left: 42.5px;
  margin-right: 42.5px;
}
#health_profile_ico {
  float: left;
}
.long {
  height: 180px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: #0288d1;
  display: inline-block;
}
.short {
  height: 180px;
  width: 225px;
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="long">
    <object class="icon" id="health_profile_ico" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/health_profile_icon.svg" width="140px" height="140px" alt="health profile"></object>
    <h2 id="health_profile_title">Health <br /> Profile</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="short">
    <object class="icon" id="short_ico" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/chat_icon.svg" width="140px" height="140px" alt="chat"></object>
  </div>
  <div class="short">
    <object class="icon" id="short_ico" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/nearby_place_icon.svg" width="140px" height="140px" alt="nearby locations finder"></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

please help me fast cause i need to solve this problem and finish the project
I generated the expected result using photoshop and I am sure of them

Comment: What browser are you viewing this in?

Comment: In the code you provided, the #content is centered. There must be something else somewhere on your page adding space on the right

Comment: i am using chrome the newest version

Comment: @henry please explain more i dont understand

Comment: can you submit an answer with the needed code

Comment: It seems that @henry is right.  I've copied your code into my own file and it appears centered in my browser (Chrome).  There must be something else in your file that is putting it off balance.

Comment: @MohamedSherifNoureldin Have you tried `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto` in your `#content` section?

Comment: This is how your code renders http://imgur.com/a/561wb. So two things: 1) there's something missing, that would make the boxes align correctly, and 2) the extra space on the right is coming from somewhere else

Comment: btw my guess is someone downvoted you for the "please help me fast". Everyone here is just helping in their free time, and some times it will take days or even weeks to get an answer. It can be frustrating (it's happened to me too), but that's how SO works! :)

Comment: i will try @cameronroytaylor and tell you

Comment: i tried but it doesn't change

Comment: @henry the screenshot there is the render of the code

Comment: I believe you! But that's not how your code looks when I test it

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is the result of your `#short_ico` *margin-right* property; so adding the following code to your css should resolve the problem:

```
.short:nth-last-child(1) #short_ico {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```